# Microsoft Compiler in Docker

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, docker, dockerfile

I want to setup a Docker container to support builds of the code base which is entirely written in C++, and the generated application runs on Windows only.

For this purpose, I need to setup a container replicating our current build environment to support the builds.

I need to create a Dockerfile something like below to build such a container:

Please consider the following as kind of pseudo-code Dockerfile(ignore the apt-get and consider any other utility in windows to install tools from command line):

```
FROM: Windows10 // A base windows kernel 

RUN apt-get install -y VisualStudio // Installing the Visual Studio for compilation of C++ files

RUN apt-get install -y cygwin // Since I am using some cygwin utlities in build process

RUN apt-get install -y SigningTool // A tool I need to sign the exe

RUN apt-get install -y CompressionTool // A tool I need to compress the exe

RUN apt-get install -y BuildSystem // Custom in-house build system to generate the builds of the source code

CMD ['BuildSystem debug']
```

**Note:** We have a **custom build system** ( and not using GNU Make) in our organization to perform the builds. debug is the target provided to the build system, since I want to build a debug executable.

My **doubts** are:

1. How do I **install a VisualStudio compiler** ( or any other compiler that runs on windows)
2. How do I **host** the SigningTool , CompressionTool and other **executables** (on **Docker Trusted Registry**; whether is it possible to host the executables on DTR)
3. How do I take care of the **licensing** of the above tools (compiler, signingtool, compressiontool all require licenses to run).

The above works absolutely fine in our organization. 
But the process of setting up a machine (installation and all of the above tools takes a lot of time and effort).
Hence, I want to create a Docker image that can be deployed on a bare machine, which will have the whole build environment setup and running in very less time.

A more important purpose of doing so is to adopt the **Continuous Delivery** methodology.

Please provide your inputs on the same(try to consider all the doubts).

Answer (score 9):

I assume you can already run Windows containers, ex. `docker run -it microsoft/windowsservercore`

Here is my **Dockerfile** to install Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 in Docker container using **Chocolatey**:

```
# escape=`

FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

# Install chocolatey
RUN @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "(iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))) >$null 2>&1"

# Install Visual C++ Build Tools, as per: https://chocolatey.org/packages/visualcpp-build-tools
RUN choco install visualcpp-build-tools -version 14.0.25420.1 -y

# Add msbuild to PATH
RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin"

# Test msbuild can be accessed without path
RUN msbuild -version

CMD [ "cmd.exe" ]
```

Using Choco is simpler, but you can get the same result with downloading **native web installer** and running it in quiet mode, for example:

```
visualcppbuildtools_full.exe /Q /L <LogFile> /Full
```

Answer (score 6):

In answer to your first point only: there is a document here that I used as a starting point for a Docker image to compile a Windows C++ application: 
[Install Build Tools into a Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container)

I am running Docker on Windows Server 2016 and compiling a legacy application that targets XP.

My eventual `Dockerfile` looked like this:

```
# Use the latest Windows Server Core image.
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

# Download the Visual Studio 2017 installer outside of the PATH.
# This is required for Windows SDK 7.1A (XP targetting)
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_professional.exe C:\\TEMP\\vs_professional.exe

# Add C:\Bin to PATH and install Build Tools with components we need
RUN setx /m PATH "%PATH%;C:\Bin" \
&& C:\TEMP\vs_professional.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Static.Analysis.Tools \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreBuildTools \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATLMFC \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATL \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.16299.Desktop \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.16299.UWP \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.16299.UWP.Native \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Win81 \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.14.Latest \
    --add Microsoft.Component.VC.Runtime.UCRTSDK \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WinXP \
|| IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0

# Start developer command prompt with any other commands specified.
ENTRYPOINT "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" &&

# Default to PowerShell if no other command specified.
CMD ["powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

Comment: This is super cool! Is there any update for visual c++ 2019?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, you would need docker for Windows for this.

And I am not talking about [Docker for Mac and Windows Beta](https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/), which would run a *Linux* (Alpine) host on a Hyper-V VM on Windows: that would not run any Windows image, only Linux images.

I am talking about Docker for Windows (provided your [Windows10 has the latest Hyper-V feature](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2016/04/01/build-2016-container-announcements-hyper-v-containers-and-windows-10-and-powershell-for-docker/)). Up to very recently, that was only possible on a [Windows Server 2016 TP4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/virtualization/windowscontainers/deployment/system_requirements).